# Masking with shaders don't work with OpenGL ES 2 but works with OpenGL 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have the following code which work good in libgdx desktop port that runs OpenGL 2.0
but it is doesn't work with libgdx android port that runs with OpenGL ES 2.
any idea why?

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

public class MaskImage extends Actor
{
    ShaderProgram program;
    Texture texture0;
    Texture mask;

    final String vertexShader = 
        "uniform mat4 u_projView;\n" + 
        "attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" + 
        "attribute vec2 " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n"   + 
        "attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" + 
        "uniform sampler2D u_mask;\n" + 
        "varying vec4 vColor;\n" + 
        "varying vec2 vTexCoord;\n" + 
        "void main(){\n" + 
        "   vColor = " + ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" + 
        "   vTexCoord = " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" + 
        "   gl_Position =  u_projView * " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n"
        + "}\n";

final String fragmentShader = 

     "varying lowp vec4 vColor;\n" +
     "uniform sampler2D u_mask;\n" +
     "varying lowp vec2 vTexCoord;\n" +
     "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" +
     "void main(void)\n" +
     "{\n" +
     "    highp float mask;\n"+
     "    lowp vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord);\n" +
     "    mask = texture2D(u_mask, vTexCoord).a;\n" +
     "    gl_FragColor = vColor * texColor * mask;\n" +
     "}\n";

    public MaskImage()
    {
    texture0 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/grass.png"));
    mask = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/msk.png"));

    program = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    mask.bind();

    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    texture0.bind();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha)
    {
    program.begin();
    program.setUniformi("u_mask", 1);
    batch.draw(texture0, 200, 200);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I added precision to the relevant vars and it as no errors

Comment: Fetch the log of the shader (`Gdx.app.log("SHADER", program.getLog()`).  The problem is as likely an issue with the GPU's shader compiler as GL/vs GL ES.

Comment: Thanks. I had some errors now they all fixed but still it is not working with OpenGL ES 2

Comment: Can you include some screenshots that demonstrate what is happening?  Also, please include the make/model of your GPU.